# CiscoPacketTracerProblem(Subnetting)

Tags: networking, cisco

I have homework in Networking and I need help to solve a problem in Subnetting.

I need to insert in packet tracer the information of the problem.
This is my homework problem if anyone can help me to solve this
[image: Picture]

Comment: Hi, welcome to SO. StackOverflow is not a homework site. Please make sure to ask a **specific question about programming** by creating a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). What have you tried so far? How far did you get? What error messages are you getting?

Answer (score 0):

You did the hard job! which was subnetting and form the question, you don't need to configure routing protocol, so you only just assign IP addresses to routers and PCs. Which you can do it using DHCP or manually. It'll look like this:

[image]

You can search on YouTube there are lots of tutorials on how to configure routers, switches and PCs.

Answer (score 0):

If you have to only put the ips this is the solution using variable mask
IP: 172.16.0.0 Mask:255.255.0.0
Networks:
60 host: 172.16.0.0-172.16.0.63 Mask:255.255.255.192
24 host: 172.16.0.64-172.16.0.95 Mask:255.255.255.224
15 host: 172.16.0.96-172.16.0.127 Mask:255.255.255.224
2 host(the routers): 172.16.0.128-172.16.0.131 Mask:255.255.255.252

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).